# "Bedeutung" und "Tragweite"

Tags: word-choice

> **Tragweite**: Ausmaß, in dem sich etwas [ziemlich weitreichend] auswirkt; >
>
> Synonyme: Bedeutung, Belang, Gewicht, Größe, Rang, Stellenwert, Tiefe,
> Wert, Wichtigkeit
>
> **Bedeutung:**
>
> 1. a. Sinn, der in Handlungen, Gegebenheiten, Dingen, Erscheinungen liegt
>    b. das Bedeuten; begrifflicher Inhalt eines Zeichens; Beziehung zwischen Wortkörper und begrifflichem Inhalt
> 2. a.Gewicht, Tragweite, Belang
>    b. Geltung, Ansehen, Wert

Quelle: Duden

Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen "Bedeutung" und "Tragweite" oder sind sie austauschbar?

Comment: Du hast es doch schon gefunden. 1a) ist eine Bedeutung von *Bedeutung*, die *Tragweite* nicht haben kann.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

direkt austauschbar sind die beiden Begriffe nicht.

Die "Tragweite" weist auf die Konsequenzen und Auswirkungen, beispielsweise eines Ereignisses, hin.

Die "Bedeutung" ist zunächst rein die inhaltliche Beschreibung oder Erklärung / Erläuterung eines Begriffes. Im Sinne des Synonyms "Tragweite" würde ich eher das Adjektiv (bedeutend) verwenden.

Comment: Man kann doch ein Adjektiv nicht als Synonym für ein Substantiv verwenden!