# Bedeutung von "beackern"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Auch die sozialen 
>   Netzwerke werden mittlerweile von Journalisten **beackert**: So verfassen etwa Social-Media-Redakteure 
>   für ihre Redaktionen oder für Kunden professionelle
>   Beiträge auf Facebook, Twitter und Co.

In diesem Satz wurde das Verb *beackern* offenbar im übertragenen Sinne verwendet. Wie kann man dieses Verb umschreiben und ist überhaupt solcher Satz typisch?

Comment: Wieder einmal kann ich mit Ihrer Frage nichts anfangen. Wie sie vermutlich bereits wissen (denn das war bei all' Ihren Bedeutung-von-Fragen, in denen die Antwort schon stand, auch schon der Fall), wird beim Beackern ein Acker landwirtschaftlich **bearbeitet**. Also kann das Verb **beackern** offensichtlich durch das Verb **bearbeiten** umschrieben werden.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich Im Beispielssatz ist allerdings nicht von Acker die Rede, sondern von sozialen Netzwerken. Und die Umschreibung brauche ich, um den Satz besser zu verstehen

Comment: Sie haben doch schon in Ihrer Frage festgestellt, dass es "im übertragenen Sinne verwendet" wurde. Aber das ist genau, was ich meine: Sie stellen immer wieder Fragen, deren Antworten Sie schon gegeben haben. Und dann weiß man nicht, was Sie eigentlich wollen, und es bleibt nur, das bereits Gesagte nochmal zu wiederholen. Das ist nicht Sinn und Zweck dieser Seite.

Comment: ... Am schärfsten fand ich Beiträge wie https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38406/bedeutung-und-tragweite, wo Sie Duden-Definitionen zweier Wörter angeben und dann nach dem Bedeutungsunterschied der Wörter fragen. Verzeihen Sie mir, wenn ich Ihnen Unrecht tue, aber bei der Häufigkeit solcher Fragen kommt man sich langsam veralbert vor.

Comment: Für mich als Nicht-muttersprachler sind die Definitionen im Wörterbuch nicht immer nachvollziehbar, weswegen ich hier Fragen stelle, um zu wissen, wann ich ein bestimmtes Wort verwenden kann. Mich interessieren vor allem feinere Nuancen der Sprache, die ein Wörterbuch ja nicht immer erklären kann.

Comment: Vielleicht in einem Wörterbuch nachsehen? z.B.: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/beackern

Comment: Ich halte Dreikäsehochs Anliegen, zu vorhandenen (aber notorisch kurzen) Bedeutungsdefinitionen aus Wörterbüchern weitergehende Auskünfte und Meinungen einzuholen, für rechtfertigbar und unterstützenswert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Etwas zu *beackern* hat wohl mit der bildhaften Vorstellung zu tun, so wie ein Landwirt intensiv Feldarbeit zu betreiben.

*Beackern* würde ich auch so verstehen, dass ein Acker in dem Maße bewirtschaftet wird, dass jedes Stückchen davon maximal ausgenutzt wird ohne etwas auszulassen.

Im übertragenen Sinn werden dann eben die sozialen Netzwerke im gleichen Maße beackert bzw. durchpflügt - wobei *durchpflügen* wohl ebenso hergeleitet werden kann wie ersteres.

Comment: Die Bedeutungskomponente "möglichst jede Ecke ausnützen" würde ich dem Wort *beackern* weder in der direkten noch in der übertragenen Bedeutung zumessen. *Beackern* ist einfach *intensiv bearbeiten* oder *mit viel Schweiß bearbeiten* - ob nun in der Landwirtschaft auf einem realen Acker oder in einem anderen Berufs**feld** [q.e.d.].